# Wifi connection fail, but web connects with wire connection

Tags: wireless, wired

I can use web Firefox/Chromium with the (home) wire connection,
but, since a few days, internet stopped working through wifi (same home) connection.

The strange thing is ftp (fireftp) works, and Thunderbird emailer seems also to work properly.

Ubuntu 14.04, no proxy, it is at home and has been functioning for years without this problem! Restarted the box (bbox), not solving. Problem is the same under Windows 7, so Ubuntu not in cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an unknown reason, today it worked again, internet connection is ok through the wifi. Maybe an issue from my Internet Service Provider?